# What is the point of outer in a join?

Tags: sql-server, join

I have made a script which harvests mac addresses from switch ports and puts them in a database. I insert it into an import table to be copied over later to the real table. All fine. Now I am writing the query to find which mac addresses are new. So, I need the rows in the import table which are not in the destination table. A left outer join makes sense:

```
select *
from SwitchportMac_import i
left outer join SwitchportMac sm 
on sm.switch = i.switch and sm.port = i.port and sm.mac = i.mac
```

This returns also rows in `i` which match in `sm`. Sure, I can add a `where sm.id is null` but I am flabbergasted.

So either:

- I am an idiot and did something obviously wrong
- I am an idiot and have been explaining and understanding joins wrong for 20 years

If it's the first I will dump the DDL and figure it out but I'm scared it's the second one. Does the outer keyword exist just to confuse me?

Comment: Why not use `EXCEPT` to [returns distinct rows from the left input query that aren't output by the right input query.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)???

Comment: Personally, I'd say it doesn't exist to confuse you, it exists to allow you to be a bit more explicit. Just like `AS` and `INNER`, it's really never needed, but it makes it more explicit what's happening (that it's an outer and not an inner join). In my experience, the use of `INNER` is more common than the use of `OUTER`, but they both serve no real function.

Comment: Thank you for the ``EXCEPT`` suggestion, that seems what I want. I don't want to join the tables I want to filter a set.

Comment: Learn what LEFT JOIN ON returns: INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN ON you want as part of an OUTER JOIN ON. After a LEFT JOIN ON, a WHERE or INNER JOIN that requires a right [sic] table column to be not NULL removes any rows with introduced NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN ON rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`LEFT JOIN` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN` are synonymous so apologies but it sounds like option 2 :-)

The "Outer" join (which preserves unmatched rows) is as opposed to "Inner" (which doesn't).

There are three flavours of outer join. Left, Right, Full (dependent on which unmatched rows are to be preserved).

As SQL doesn't have direct join syntax for any other types of join (such as left/right anti semi join) there is no ambiguity in allowing the `OUTER` keyword be optional in the grammar.

The `LEFT ANTI SEMI JOIN` sounds like what you expected `LEFT OUTER` to do. You can implement that in [a variety of ways](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join). Usually `NOT EXISTS` is preferred but you can use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in conjunction with `IS NULL` to keep only the non matched ones.

This is all confirmed in the "[Join type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#join-type)" section of the documentation

> `LEFT [ OUTER ]` Specifies that all rows from the left table not
>   meeting the join condition are included in the result set, and output
>   columns from the other table are set to `NULL` in addition to all rows
>   returned by the inner join.

The square brackets around the `[OUTER]` just mean that this is optional but nonetheless the same definition applies.

Comment: The problem arises from the left + outer. I assumed looking at a Venn diagram that this ment the outer part. And the left the whole left circle. Well, I was wrong, lesson learnt.

Comment: @user189695 We can group output rows from `x full outer join y on c` in a diagram that looks like a Venn diagram, with the left & right circles being (respectively) `x left/right outer join on c` rows & with `x inner join y on c` as the intersection & `x full outer join on c` as the union. The 2 outer crescents are the unmatched rows of the (respectively) left/right tables extended by `null`s.

Answer (score 4):

This would be my preferred way to get what you want, using a correlated sub-query with EXISTS.  Assuming you have an index on both tables on switch, port and mac, this should be good performance as well.

```
SELECT *
FROM SwitchportMac_import i
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT TOP (1) 1 
    FROM SwitchportMac sm 
    WHERE sm.switch = i.switch 
      and sm.port = i.port 
      and sm.mac = i.mac
)
```

Comment: Are there any advantages using TOP in EXISTS subquery? As soon as 1 row is found the whole predicate is false, so the DBMS should be able to figure that out?

Comment: Hmm, maybe not.  I like the formatting but this seems to indicate no benefit and no harm.  https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2011/04/05/to-top-or-not-to-top-an-exists/

Comment: I use some old habits myself which has no practical meaning anymore, so I was just curious if this was something like that, or if it has an impact on how well the query executes.

Answer (score 3):

> from SwitchportMac_import i LEFT OUTER JOIN SwitchportMac sm
>
> This returns rows in i which match in sm.

Correct.  That's exactly what a LEFT [OUTER] JOIN does - it gets you *everything* in the "left" table (i) whether or not it can find a matching row in the "right" table (sm).

To get "new" items (those that appear in the "left" table but not the "right"), you *do need* to include that "is null" test *as well*.  This is commonly known as an "exclusion join".

Answer (score 1):

`where sm.id is null` is needed to match the rows that don't exist in the join.

Left joins are always `OUTER` so its syntactic sugar invented by committee. They where thinking of confusing you and others ahead of time. You're not a idiot, confusion was implemented as planned.

Answer (score 1):

LEFT join says "take all rows from the left i.e. preceeding table i.e. SwitchportMac_import". You don't want all rows from that table, only the ones that do not match.

Adding the IS NULL will work. I think a NOT EXISTS would better suit your needs here.